# Time to guess a 100-bit key at one billion operations per second and one billion cores?

Tags: brute-force-attack

My math is as follows. If you can do one billion operations per second on a single core, and you have one billion cores available, that translates to $2^{60}$ operations per second, and $2^{100}$/$2^{60}$ = $2^{40}$ seconds, which translates to ~35,000 years.

Increase the key length to 128 bits, and the time required becomes greater than the age of the universe.

Is the math here correct?

Comment: @PaulUszak Please refrain from using comments for purposes other than asking for clarification or making suggestions to improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your math is correct. That is why 128-bit keys are considered secure.